# C# Refactoring/Renaming Removing Numeric Literal 'f' from float parameters in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, refactoring, rename

I want to remove the trailing 'f' from all floats in the current document, without touching 'f's from other words/methods in a cs. code file. It has more than 450 * 4 occurrences that I want to change, so it's a hell to do by hand.

I've tried using the Regex find/replace in VS2019 which did find all the occurrences I want to change, but I can't change it in the same way. 
How do I keep the number and remove the trailing 'f' from it?

The attached screenshot has the regex and the attempt at replacing it (and for those who can't open the screenshot: `(?<![A-Za-z])[0-9.]+f` is the regex used to find the numbers + f)

Thanks in advance!

[Visual Studio Refactor Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWUOD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a capturing group to match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part:

```
(?<![A-Za-z])([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)f
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QOHVUl/1)

In the replacement use group 1 followed by the replacement.

You might add a word boundary after `f\b` to prevent it being part of a larger word.

---

Another option is to match the f only adding adding matching the number in the lookbehind

```
(?<![A-Za-z][0-9]+(?:\.\[0-9]+)?)f\b
```

See a .NET [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5bA-Za-z%5d%5b0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5c%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%3f%29f%5cb&i=1f%2c+71f)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This worked perfectly and thanks for the word boundary suggestion!